# Having trouble getting jQuery tooltip function to work

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tooltip

I'm having a problem with the tooltip functionality I'm trying to implement on a project.
I'm using the jQuery library that is described here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/

The (test) website can be found here: http://wandree.websites.xs4all.nl/test/

When I hover over the menu item called 'Zoeken' I want the div #search to appear. When I use Firebug I can see that the div does get opacity 1 and display: block. However I can't see the searchform anywhere on the screen.... I've looked anywhere but the div remains frustratingly elusive.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something really simple. Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is appearing underneath your carousel, due to the

```
top: 200px !important;
```

...that is attached to #menu.popup.

Remove this, and you should see the tooltip.

By the way, if you want to work within Firebug while simulating a hover on the "Zoeken" menu item, enter the following in your console:

```
$('#menu h4.last').trigger("mouseover");
```

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to track it down and position it a bit better. I've noticed that the div #menu.popup can only be displayed within the confines of the div .bubbleInfo, but I'd really like it to be displayed slightly below the menu bar. Any idea on how to break the div out of its enclosing div?